# How do I display an image that comes from an intent in an imageView in my app in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-image

I am using an intent to launch my app when an image is selected (for example a bitmoji). I want the image to be displayed in an image view.

This is the relevant code in my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
             if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                 handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
             } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
             }
        }
    void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    //
    try
    {
        //bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver() ,  imageUri);
        if (imageUri != null) {

            // Update UI to reflect image being shared

            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();
            //bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver() , imageUri);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //handle exception
    }


}
```

I've done some debugging, so I know the Uri has a string to a file, it's just not updating the imageView. From doing some reading I think I may need to inflate the View first? I'm unclear on this. I'm pretty new to Android, a little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you put handleSendImage() method in onCreate() ??

Comment: Yes. The function is called from onCreate(). There is a Uri for the image, so it is in memory, I am just not inserting it properly into imageView as best as I can tell. Or, maybe I need to run the decode of the bitmap as a background thread using AsyncTask ?

Comment: yes exactly try that

Comment: Ok, I am doing all that now - using an Async task as well as decoding the bitmap, but now I get the following error:
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bitstrips.imoji/cache/bitmoji-1441479250.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

@Nisarg, any ideas what this error is?

Comment: your targetSdk is 23 ?